# capture word a or b and part of optional extra arguments

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

First of all this doesn't match `ok or capture` `"ok".find("(ok|capture)") -- nil`

Second, followed by `ok` match an optional `ok;args` but only capture `args` as parameter. This is wrong `"ok;args".find("(ok)(;.+)?")`, and capture group includes extra `;`.

```
function mymatch(str)
  local _, _, ok, oreveal = str:find("(ok)")
  return ok, oreveal
end

-- this is what I want
print(mymatch("ok")) -- ok nil
print(mymatch("cancel")) -- cancel nil
print(mymatch("ok;domatch")) -- ok domatch
print(mymatch("okdontmatch")) -- nil nil
```

Comment: `ok(?:;(.+))?`?

Comment: Lua patterns are not regexps, e.g. the lack of alternation operator proves this. So you can't use *match this or that* logic in the pattern itself in Lua patterns.

Comment: no, if there is no idiomatic solution, I can drop `cancel` and just match on `ok`, but an optional argument would be nice.

Comment: `"ok".find("(ok|capture)")` and `"ok;args".find("(ok)(;.+)?")` are invalid syntax.  also string.find does not return 4 values with only one capture so in `local _, _, ok, oreveal = str:find("(ok)")` `oreveal` will always be `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```lua
function mymatch(str)
  local _, _, ok, oreveal = str:find("^(ok%f[%A]);?(.*)$")
  if ok == nil then
    _, _, ok, oreveal = str:find("^(cancel%f[%A]);?(.*)$")
  end
  if oreveal == "" then
    oreveal = nil
  end
  return ok, oreveal
end

-- this is what I get
print(mymatch("ok")) -- ok nil
print(mymatch("cancel")) -- cancel nil
print(mymatch("ok;domatch")) -- ok domatch
print(mymatch("okdontmatch")) -- nil nil
```

See the [online Lua demo](https://ideone.com/Peujph).

The `^(ok%f[%A]);?(.*)$` pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `(ok%f[%A])` - Group 1: `ok` and a trailing "word boundary" (`%f[%A]` is a frontier pattern making sure that the next char if present must be a non-letter)
- `;?` - an optional `;`
- `(.*)` - Group 2: the rest of the string
- `$` - end of string.